# what port do use for vpn?

Tags: vpn, port

Hi fellow sysadmins! :-)

At the moment I'm running an OpenVPN server on a non standard port.
Unfortunately this make some roadwarriors unable to connect because of traffic limitations depending on where they are. Sometimes they only have 53,80,443 open or there is traffic shapping applied to all ports besides there ones.

What do you normally use to avoid these issues?

Answer (score 3):

I run the server with multiple ports open (53, 80, 443 etc.) and configure the client to try them all. Order the ports after how often they tend to work. In the worst case connection takes some time.